What's difference between passed navigation controller and created navigation controller?
Each UIViewController has a UINavigationController:
// case1
A_viewController.navigationController

// case2
let B_viewController = B_ViewController(navController: A_viewController.navigationController)
B_viewController.navigationController

// case3
let navController = UINavigationController()

In case 1, 2: Why do they have each a navigationController? If navigationController is singleton object, isn't there any problem? Do they share another navigation stack?
In case 1, 2, 3: What's the difference between view controller's navigation controller and created navigation controller?

A navigation controller isn't a singleton. You should only have one in your navigation stack, but you can have multiple navigation stacks (eg each tab in a tab bar controller might have its own navigation controller). A view controller's navigationcontroller is how you find the navigation controller that is presenting the view controller. It is set when you push a view controller into a navigation controller stack. Case 3 allocates a UINavigationController.

@Paulw11 Is navigation stack consist of navigationController or viewController?

A navigation controller is a UIViewController subclass that manages a stack of view controllers

Your code for case 2 makes no sense. No one would ever write code like that. Why would you try to pass one view controller's navigation controller to another view controller?

@HangarRash  I didn't used that code. I'm just curious about difference passed navigation controller and B_viewController's navigation controller.
what's differencepassedNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true) and B_viewController.navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
